# Adding display text to a text property?

Tags: css

I have a style sheet that is used to display server status text and a colored bar (green = good, red = down, yellow = maintenance).

The way I have these set up are:

```
#status.Normal{
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:700;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    background: url(images/greenbar.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#status.Down{
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:700;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    background: url(images/red.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

And the way they are used is just by declaring Normal or Down in my server list xml file.

For example, if the site status was normal for a site the xml would read:

```
    <site name="template"> 
        <title>Title</title>
        <systemStatus>Normal</systemStatus>
        <networkNotes>notes etc</networkNotes>
        <maintenanceInformation>
                information about maintenance etc. 
        </maintenanceInformation>
    </site>
```

The HTML where this is used:

```
        <td>
            <tr><td id="status"></td></tr>
        </td>
```

The HTML reads from the "status" in the XML and the site would get the "Normal" and the green bar and show those as the status for that server based on the CSS.

Is there a way, with my current setup, to declare a new property in the css (translating to French for French users currently) where I can make the new property (for "Down") as:

```
#status.EnPanne{
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:700;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    background: url(images/red.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

And have the text display on the red bar be `En panne` instead of `EnPanne`?

Basically I'm trying to add a custom text attribute to the EnPanne property so that it displays what I want it to while still using the right property.

Edit:
With the solution posted by jme, I was able to produce these results.

[image]
Below is an example of what the English "Down" status will display, above is what I need to do for French display.  It appears that the follow-up text is cutting off the "redbar.jpg" and preventing the bar from extending to the other end of the page.

I would assume my two options here are somehow force the redbar over the following text or somehow remove that following text so the bar can fully stretch to the end of the page?

Edit 2:
Here is the portion of the script that connects the XML with the html and CSS - specifically for the system status:

```
<script> <!--Loads the Status_Pages.xml file-->
var root = null;
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $.get("Status_Page.xml",
    function (xml)
    {
        ...

        var status=$(root).find("systemStatus").text();
        $("td#status").html(status);
        $("td#status").attr("class", status);
        ...
     });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I would do this is to simply set the class attribute and allow your css to add the content, versus adding the status text into the table cell in your ajax call.  So, to do this you would **remove** this line: `$("td#status").html(status);`

Then in your css you could do this:

```
#status{
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:700;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}
#status.Normal{
    background: url(images/greenbar.jpg) no-repeat;
}
#status.EnPanne, #status.Down {
    background: url(images/red.jpg) no-repeat;
}
/*Now set your messages*/
#status.EnPanne:before {
    content: "Le système est en panne";
}
#status.Normal:before {
    content: "Operations Normal";
}
#status.Down:before {
    content: "The system is currently down";
}
```

Here's a fiddle **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/ELAec/)**.

If you're against the idea of not adding the text into the table cell, here is an example that uses a technique to hide the table cell text while absolutely positioning the content: **[demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/ELAec/2/)**.  If you want an explanation of this method, let me know.

Comment: The problem with this is because the way I have it set up (XML, CSS, and HTML) I get *sort of* the right results.  I do see "En panne" with red behind it, but the redbar.jpg doesn't extend to the edge of the screen like it should and right after the words with the red background, I have "EnPanne" (how it's being called in the XML) so I have the text twice and only one of the pieces has the red background.

Comment: You can set the pseudo element for the content to be positioned absolutely.  This way it would not be in the flow of the document and therefore not affect your redbar.jpg image and you can then position the text exactly where you want.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit your answer with an example of this?  I feel like this is on the right track.

Comment: jme, I edited the question to include the results of what you gave me.

Comment: Can you show what the generated mark up looks like?  In other words, after the xml is read in, how does the html look.  You should be able to use the developer tools in your browser or view source and just copy and paste into your question.  Then I can provide a very precise answer.

Comment: It's already in my question.  As I mentioned, that value is never actually in the HTML it's in the CSS and XML.  I did this so that the people who will be using the XML to actually make changes to the changable parts of the site will be able to just edit the 1 file and not have to worry about the html at all.

Comment: Is the text "EnPanne" coming from the xml systemStatus?  Perhaps you can just set it to display: none.

Comment: The `<systemStatus>` portion of the XML takes one of the following values: "Normal, Down, Investigating" and their French translations.  The only French translation that is more than a single word is "En panne."  Once one of those words is typed into that area of the XML, it looks in the CSS and will look at `#status.____` where `_____` is either normal, down, etc.  It then just displays the text of the status property.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on how you're parsing/reading the xml.  Are you using XSLT? Is it loading via an AJAX call using jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: Yes it's loading via an AJAX call using Javascript.  I tried XSLT and it didn't work as well as this did.

Answer (score 1):

What about escaping a space?

```
#status.En\ Panne {...}
```

And in your XML normally

```
<systemStatus>En Panne</systemStatus>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work.  I see the text, but the actual property from the CSS is not selected and the red bar does not display behind the text.  If I change the name of the property to just `Panne` and use that in the XML, it works fine - but that's technically the incorrect translation.

Comment: Strange. I have no experience with XML, CSS syntax should be correct. http://jsfiddle.net/QzvMh/, http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes (look for `whitespace characters` headline).

Comment: In that fiddle you sent me, change the top right box to `#status.a\ b {background: red;}` and you'll see the problem I'm having.  It displays the text just fine but not the attributes.

Comment: Sure, it can´t work, it´s HTML and CSS, not XML (`.` means attribute class, not element inner text)

Comment: I mean it works fine for my examples above "Normal" and "Down" but as soon as I try to add a second word or space escape it doesn't give me what I need.  Is there no way I can just call it `#status.EnPanne{..} and give it custom display text?

Comment: I've provided an edit to the original post including where in the HTML that is being used and hopefully that sheds some light as to how this all works and if I can get this to work for me.

Comment: What should `text:En panne;` in your CSS do? You have to close into quotes or escape a space too.

Comment: Oops I thought that was deleted (it originally had quotes), that was my attempt to name the property `EnPanne` and have the display text of `En panne` which translates to french as "Broken down" (Down status).

Comment: Can you please make me a fiddle using HTML/CSS, not the source XML? Show me, what HTML you have generated exactly.

Comment: The site is built so that the XML is required for functionality.  I made these so that people with little tech experience can just edit the XML and change portions of the site as needed.  The entire site isn't like this, only things that are predicted to change often.